# Unable to Initialize TDSE object. Error Code: 0x80040302 (-2147220734)

Tags: tridion

I am setting up Tridion R 5.3 content Manger server on Win 2003 Server. My Windows server is not having Active directory service enabled. The Impersonation user that I have set in Tridion Configuration Manager is

WORKGROUP\mtsuser

since the 2003 server is not under any Domain. Now whenever I try accessing console on //localhost/ and enter my credentials for mts user. The following error is shown with Mesaage on Console reading as "You dont have permission to access R 5.3 contact Administrator."

**Event Type:    Warning 

Event Source:    Kernel

Event Category:    Security

Event ID:    200

Date:        2/15/2013

Time:        2:11:23 PM

User:        WORKGROUP\mtsuser

Computer:    WORKGROUP

Description:

Unable to Initialize TDSE object.

Access is denied for the user WORKGROUP\mtsuser.

Error Code:

0x80040302 (-2147220734)

Call stack:

SystemBLST.GetUserContext

SystemBLST.IBLSecurityST_GetUserContext

TDSE.Initialize**

Please help In dire need of a solution....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your machine is not under domain then where does `WORKGROUP\mtsuser` come from? Who is managing its credentials? I think you should use `local machine name\mtsuser` and manage credentials locally. Besides you are not supposed to be able to access CME with MTSUser. This user is system user and is only to be used by the system. Also, as you are on 5.3 version, you should check documentation and make sure you've granted all the necessary rights and permissions to this user.

And you should really consider one of the supported versions of Tridion

Comment: WORKGROUP is nothing but the machine name and mtsuser is created on this machine with admin rights that I am having. so I use MachineName\mtsuser in otherwords Workgroup\mtsuser. I have gone through the Tridion R 5.3 doc and have done what ever is possible.

Comment: Are there any other messages in the event log? Is your license in place?

Comment: Yup the licences are in place. And the above message is from Tridion Content Manager event log only

Comment: If it says you don't have access, you probably don't. Check if this account name is listed in the TRUSTEES table.

Answer (score 2):

1. MTSUser should not be set as an impersonation user, this is your SYSTEM account
2. "Access is denied" means literally that the user doesn't have permissions for a given action. Maybe it's not an allowed Tridion user, since you don't have access to Tridion I'd recommend looking at the TRUSTEES table, and finding the MTSUser account there. If it doesn't match, then it certainly will not work. Add a record to the TRUSTEES table with the correct information.
3. As user978511 states, 5.3 is pretty old (early 2008), and not officially supported anymore, but I doubt you can do anything about that.
4. The impersonation account should be the same account that runs the application pool in IIS - by default this is `Network Service`

Comment: Do the Trustees Table exist on a Server on which Directory services are not enable and is not configured under a domain. The one which i am working on is a standalone server with no directory service and no domain.

Comment: The TRUSTEES table is part of the Tridion database - without that one Tridion will not work for sure.

Comment: But Nuno it is breaking at the component level and to access database I have configure the user in Tridion Configuration Manager Snapin. That use exists in Trustees Table I checked.

Comment: "Access is denied for the user WORKGROUP\mtsuser". Are you sure it is in the TRUSTEES table? Otherwise it could be a COM+ permission issue, do you have any other error logged in your Application or System logs (Windows Event viewer)